# Is it possible to select a column of dates in Google Sheets and change just the month?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet with a different sheet for each month, and while I'm duplicating the sample data realized it would be easier to just select a column and change the month without changing the day or year.

Is something like that possible?

For example, something like this:

| Old Date | Change Date to |
| --- | --- |
| 1/15/2023 | 4/15/2023 |
| 1/16/2023 | 4/16/2023 |
| 1/17/2023 | 4/17/2023 |
| 1/18/2023 | 4/18/2023 |
| 1/19/2023 | 4/19/2023 |
| 1/20/2023 | 4/20/2023 |
| 1/21/2023 | 4/21/2023 |
| 1/22/2023 | 4/22/2023 |
| 1/23/2023 | 4/23/2023 |
| 1/24/2023 | 4/24/2023 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Edit > Find and replace** dialog box to search for a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) like `^1/` and replace those substrings with `4/`.

To do this with a formula, use `edate()`, like this:

```
=map( 
  A2:A, 
  lambda( 
    date, 
    if( isdate_strict(date), edate(date, 3), iferror(1/0) ) 
  ) 
)
```

To do the same with a variable month offset, put the number of months to offset in a cell, say `N1`, and replace the `3` in the formula with `N1`. You can then hide the *Old Date* column and use the formula result column in its place.

To make the formula results editable, replace old dates with formula results by using **Edit > Paste special > Paste values only**, and remove the formula.

Another way to automate the process would be to use a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but I think I should have clarified, my apologies.

This will be a user editable field, so I don't want to use a formula for it, I just want to leave it as a regular date value just iterate the month by n. Does that make sense?

Comment: Edited the answer per your new requirements. Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. In the new question, specify the [google-apps-script] tag if you require a scripted solution.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: excellent answer +10

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! The requirements didn't change, I just clarified what I was looking for. This isn't my first question on StackOverflow, but I haven't logged in in some time.

Comment: This site is [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) which is different from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

##### DROPDOWN

Add a dropdown in `C2` and use it as the month value

```
=IF(C2<>"", EDATE(A2,C2),)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

This answer simply adds to [doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169060/197518https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169060/) (which should be the accepted one) and you can incorporate `ISDATE_STRICT` for error checking as well `MAP` a range of values if applicable.